# Scheme Switch-Statement Syntax

Tags: syntax, switch-statement, scheme

What is the smartest way to create a switch statement in Scheme?

I want to check one value up against several others, if one results true the entire function should result true, otherwise false. I am not very good with the syntax in scheme.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Scheme you have [`case`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_384):

```
(case (car '(c d))
  ((a e i o u) 'vowel)
  ((w y) 'semivowel)
  (else 'consonant)) ; ==> consonant
```

As you see it compares against literal data. Thus you cannot compare the value with other variables. Then you need [`cond`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_376)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to an explicit comparison agains each value, is to use `member`:

```
> (define (vowel? x) (member x '(a e i o u))
> (vowel? 'b)
#f
```

Answer (score 1):

### Base Case

Often if you want to return a boolean value a simple boolean expression will  be enough. In the simple case several checks within an `or` will be enough:

```
(define (switch val)
  (or (equal? val 'some-value)
      (equal? val 'some-other-value)
      (equal? val 'yet-another-value)))
```

### Higher Order Function

Is we're doing this often it's a lot of work, so we can make a function called `make-switch` that takes a list of values and returns a function that serves as a switch statement for those values:

```
(define (make-switch list-of-vals)
  (define (custom-switch val)
    (define (inner vals)
      (cond ((null? vals) #f)
            ((equal? val (first vals)) #t)
            (else
             (inner (rest vals)))))
    (inner list-of-vals))
```

Then we can use `make-switch` like this:

```
> (define k (make-switch '(1 2 a "b")))
> (k 1)
#t
> (k 5)
#f
> (k "a")
#f
> (k "b")
#t
```

### Faster Lookups

If we're mostly checking against a static set of values, then a hash-table is another alternative. This code in `#lang racket` shows the general approach, an R5RS Scheme could use SRFI-69:

```
#lang racket
(define (make-switch alist)
  (define (list->hash alist)
    (make-hash (map (lambda (x) (cons x x))
                    alist)))
  (lambda (val)
    (if (hash-ref (list->hash alist) val #f)
        #t
        #f)))
```

#### Note

There may be cases where you want to use `eq?` or some other test for equality, but I've left `make-custom-make-switch` as an exercise for further exploration.